# Marklogic XQY Debugger of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, marklogic, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

How do you setup the ***MarkLogic XQY Debugger*** in Visual Studio Code. Can someone direct me to actual sample example of debugging similar to the ***MarkLogic Java Script (JS) Debugger*** https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

The steps to add and configure the XQuery debugger are similar to how to configure for JavaScript debugging. When creating a new `launch.json`, select **MarkLogic XQY Debugger**, instead of **MarkLogic JS Debugger**.

Example entries are documented in the Debugging section of the [MarkLogic developer tools marketplace documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mlxprs.mlxprs#debugging), and on the GitHub project [readme](https://github.com/mikrovvelle/mlxprs#debugging):

## [Debugging](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mlxprs.mlxprs#debugging)

> Both JavaScript and XQuery debuggers support two modes of debugging:

> 1. Launch: Evaluates a main module (for JavaScript) or non-library module (for XQuery)
> 2. Attach: Intecepts an existing request, such as from an integration test
>    Where it can, query debugging uses the same VS Code settings used for running queries (for example, `marklogic.host`, `marklogic.username`). In addition to these code settings, you will need a [launch config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) in your project (under `.vscode/launch.json`) for debug-specific parameters.

> Open the `launch.json` from the VS Code command palette with the command: `Debug: Open launch.json`.

> Below is an example of a `launch.json` file, with JavaScript and XQuery configurations for both launch and attach:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "ml-jsdebugger",
      "name": "Evaluate Current JavaScript Module"
    },
    {
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "ml-jsdebugger",
      "name": "Attach to Debug Request",
      "root": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main/ml-modules/root",
      "debugServerName": "Enter debug server name"
    },
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "xquery-ml",
      "name": "Launch XQY Debug Request",
      "program": "",
      "root": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main/ml-modules/root"
    },
    {
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "xquery-ml",
      "name": "Attach to XQY Debug request",
      "root": "${workspaceFolder}/plugins"
    }
  ]
}
```